# Cant set image for UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to set image for my UIBarButtonItem and I can't manage to do that. I tried two times, and in first case I get my image in right place, but when I click on button nothing happens (it should pop out a new window, but nothing works). There is the piece of code I  have used:

```
UIImage *faceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"plus_button.png"];
    UIButton *face = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    face.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, faceImage.size.width, faceImage.size.height );
    [face setImage:faceImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   UIBarButtonItem *faceBtn = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:face]initWithImage:faceImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(addProduct:)];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = faceBtn;
```

In second case, I set image on button and new window appears as it should be, but there is not only my custom image I want, but also it show "borders", it looks like image was put in center on default button. Obviously I want only my image, not borders, only my image. There is piece of code I have used in second case:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:faceImage style:UIBarStyleDefault target:self action:@selector(addProduct:)];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = addButton;
```

Please help me to solve the problem, any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this ... change it's method, image according to you

```
UIButton *button1=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button1 setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 2.0, 45.0, 40.0)];
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(showLeft:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"left-arrow-button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:button1];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button;
```

Comment: barButtonItemClass is undeclared identifier :(

Comment: oh! i wrote it by mistake ... now i have edited please check it :-)

Comment: Yes its working! Thank you very much! Im owe so much to you :))

Answer (score 4):

Or... just write two lines of iOS 8 Swift code. (Might even work in iOS 7)

```
    let doneButtonAsLeftArrow = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "LeftArrow24x24.png"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "doneButtonPushed")
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = doneButtonAsLeftArrow
```

Answer (score 3):

I have modified your code and tested the image showing in the barbutton. Please try this by yourself. And please let me know if you face any problem on this.

```
    UIImage *faceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Badge.png"];
    UIButton *face = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    face.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, faceImage.size.width, faceImage.size.height );
    [face addTarget:self action:@selector(showAlerts) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [face setImage:faceImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIBarButtonItem *faceBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:face];    
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = faceBtn;
```

EDIT: I have added a line in my answer. I just printed a message "Hi" in log. it is working. Can you please try it?

Thanks.

Comment: Yuvaraj i greatly appreciated what you did, but i want you to mention i used "action:@selector(addProduct:)" for call my second window. Obviously its not called

Comment: Yuvaraj.M thanks everything working! I just got 2 correct answers from you and guy below, I'm so happy i solved this problem! Please accept my best wishes! :)

Answer (score 1):

Swift version of accepted answer for anyone

```
var settingsButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
settingsButton.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSize(width: 36, height: 36))
settingsButton.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
settingsButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonActionHere:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

let rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: settingsButton)
navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(rightBarButtonItem, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:faceImage style: UIButtonTypeCustom target:self action:@selector(addProduct:)];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = addButton;
```

u were creating a default button, you need to create a `UIButtonTypeCustom` type button...

Comment: Thank you, i do understand this but can't manage things out :)