# ios system Share and settings buttons

Tags: ios5

I have a task to clone an application of... I can't change the client mind, pls do not suggest it.

I can't found where is hidden in iOS this 2 buttons. I think it is coming from iOS, not just a The buttons looks like: [image: Share] and [image: Settings].

I am searching a code part, something like this:

```
refreshButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(doStuff)];
```

but can't found a button share at:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIBarButtonSystemItem) {
    UIBarButtonSystemItemDone,
    UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel,
    UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit,  
    UIBarButtonSystemItemSave,  
    UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd,
    UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace,
    UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace,
    UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose,
    UIBarButtonSystemItemReply,
    UIBarButtonSystemItemAction,
    UIBarButtonSystemItemOrganize,
    UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks,
    UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch,
    UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh,
    UIBarButtonSystemItemStop,
    UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera,
    UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash,
    UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay,
    UIBarButtonSystemItemPause,
    UIBarButtonSystemItemRewind,
    UIBarButtonSystemItemFastForward,
#if __IPHONE_3_0 <= __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
    UIBarButtonSystemItemUndo,
    UIBarButtonSystemItemRedo,
#endif
#if __IPHONE_4_0 <= __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
    UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl,
#endif
};
```

in

> UIBarButtonItem.h

Any help would be appreciated where to look at.
Need to support iOS 5.0

Edit: can't accept the answer with UIBarButtonSystemItemAction, because it looks like:

[image: Action]

As you can see, it is not the "clone" of original, bar far away, because it is missing the description ( text under icon), checked the `UITabBarSystemItem`, since those has text under icon, but nothing match the 2x images:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UITabBarSystemItem) {
    UITabBarSystemItemMore,
    UITabBarSystemItemFavorites,
    UITabBarSystemItemFeatured,
    UITabBarSystemItemTopRated,
    UITabBarSystemItemRecents,
    UITabBarSystemItemContacts,
    UITabBarSystemItemHistory,
    UITabBarSystemItemBookmarks,
    UITabBarSystemItemSearch,
    UITabBarSystemItemDownloads,
    UITabBarSystemItemMostRecent,
    UITabBarSystemItemMostViewed,
};
```

It seems need to search a custom library and get those 2 icons for or make 2x custom buttons with those images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIBarButtonSystemItemAction` is what you are looking for the Share.

The settings icon doesn't exist as a system icon so you have to use a custom button with an image.

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274052/cant-set-image-for-uibarbuttonitem) on how to create a Bar Button with a custom image

**EDIT:**

As long as the share button is not exactly the same with what you want, add two custom buttons if you want the icons to look exactly as the native ones.

*Kind reminder: Apple doesn't like it when developers immitating their custom controls when they aren't using the defaults.*

Comment: probably, checking. For Share or for Settings?

Comment: For share. You need settings too?

Comment: You can find a lot of icons same as the settings icon in iconfinder

Comment: Sash just add another answer with" make 2x custom button, there is no iOS built in button like that" to be accepted.